# Conditional probabiliy and marginalization

Tags: probability, marginal-distribution

These are some simple questions that I typically find unexplained or I guess assumed to be obvious. Say we have two random variables $X$, $Y$ and we write $P(X|Y)$, and then wish to sum over possible $X$ values: $\sum
\limits_{x \in X} P(X|Y)$, is the implication here typically that we are fixing some value of $Y$ ? Or are we doing this for every possible value of $Y$, and in a sense getting $|Y|$ marginals ? A related question, when is it obvious or how can we tell that an operation such as $\sum
\limits_{x \in X} P(X|Y)$ equals 1 and otherwise when does it not? My first thought is that we are assuming that $P(X|Y)$ follows the axioms of probability and so by definition, summing over all possible values (in the discrete case), must be equal to 1. My confusion here comes from books that say it's obvious that such statements equal one, while there are other similar statements that presumably aren't equal to one. In particular page 6, right after equation 3.12 [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/prelims/chapter3.pdf)

Comment: The notation $P(x|y)$ is usually read as "probability of x **given y**". Thus, we know that a specific $y$ value is given. Hence, we don't sum over $y$. With this explanation, is it not obvious, that the sum over all probabilities is equal to 1?

Comment: @Semoi with that explanation yes. however I was not referring to summing over y, simply iterating over it's possible values, and computing the marginal of x for each of those values.

Comment: Can you give an example/source where it doesn't equal to one? Page 6 in Jordan is an example of it being $1$.